# End Twilio Video room using TWIML

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

Is there a way to end a room once one of the participants leave?

I found a way to do it using the REST API: set a status callback and when the event is  `participant-disconnected`, update the Room's status to `completed`.

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it only with TWIML to be able to do it with my *TWIML Bin* to reduce complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio Programmable Video Rooms do not utilize TwiML, with the exception of Programmable Voice users joining a Programmable Video room using the  verb.

Your current approach using [Room Status Call Backs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-callback-events) sounds like an ideal approach, [complete a room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#complete-room).